# What is the difference between Data Class and Regular Class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, data-class

Other than the fact that the compiler automatically generates certain functions for Data Class, what is the fundamental difference between them?

Comment: See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html. Why do you think there are differences other than described?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data classes in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45069337/data-classes-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kotlin, classes declared with the `data class` keywords simply get some extra methods generated:

- equals
- hashcode
- toString
- copy
- componentX

Declaring a regular `class` and defining these methods manually yields exactly the same thing. There is no other difference at bytecode level.

You do however have some extra limitations (no non-property constructor arguments, limitations on inheritance...), but these are just compile-time limitations so that the generated methods behave in a predictable/non surprising way.

The [official doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) covers everything in detail about them.